# Javascript: ajax data's split function error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'split'"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I get the data from jQuery ajax and assigning it to a array variable. But when I call split function on this array variable I get the error (as seen in google chrome console) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'split'
```

The relevant code is:

```
$(function () {
    var originalData=[]; // Also tried var originalData=new Array(); and var originalData;
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'data.php',                    
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'text',               
      success: function(data)          
      {
        alert(data); // THIS WORKS
      }
    });

    alert("a");  // THIS WORKS
    var dataArray =originalData.split("#");
    alert("abc "+ dataArray); //THIS DOESNT WORK
});
```

Not able to crack this at all. Don't know if I am making a mistake in assuming object type of ajax data or in assigning orginalData to data.

Also the php file's output is `echo $array;` where `$array` is declared as `$array="";` and thereafter I keep appending strings to `$array`.

Also the data content is: 
#195:93.0500:94.8500:93.0500:93.6500#196:94.0000:94.4500:92.0000:92.2500#197:91.0000:92.1000:87.6500:87.6500#198:88.0000:89.0000:86.0000:87.9000#199:89.0000:92.3000:88.5000:92.2000#200:93.1000:94.1000:90.7500:91.4000

Thanks

**EDIT**

After Aashray's answer, by substituting `var originalData=[];` to `var originalData="";` I am not getting the error. However the functionality of split is not working as it shows a blank array after split.

**EDIT**

The issue of blank array does not seem related to original question. I think the problem is that $.ajax function is being called after the split function. Atleast when i put in more alerts I found that the sequence starts with alerts around split function, and the alert inside $.ajax happens at end. So the blank array after split is blank because most probably its input data was not populated by $.ajax at the time split was called. But then thats another problem unrelated to the question.

Comment: `alert(data); // THIS WORKS` can you post the output of that alert.

and also where are you assigning data to the variable `originalData`.

Comment: With regards as to your "other" problem, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593551/javascript-variable-and-passing-data-issues/13593755#13593755

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`originalData` is an array. `split()` function can only be used on strings.
Use an index to refer the location, like `originalData[0]`.

Comment: But when I declare original data as "var originalData;"  and then assign it to data, then it should work. But it doesnt.

Comment: @Aashray: It worked somewhat after i assigned var originalData="";. It alerted "abc" but did not alert the rest of the dataArray. So atleast the code recognizes the "split" function, though it isnt working properly. Thanks.

Comment: again `dataArray` is an array. I don't think there is a `toString();` function in js.

Comment: @Aashray: Marked your answer as correct as it answers my issue. I think the problem is coming that $.ajax function is being called after the split function. Atleast when i put in more alerts I found that the sequence starts with alerts around split function, and the alert inside $.ajax happens at end. So the blan array after split is blank because most probably its input data was not populated by $.ajax at the time split was called. But then thats another problem unrelated to the question.

Comment: Your `alert(data);` displays the values obtained right? where are you assigning the value of `data` to `originalData`. Check this part. If you are getting the values form ajax, then they need to be assigned to a local variable.

Comment: `var dataArray =originalData.split("#");` this line is calling split on `originalData` but where the value for `originalData` being set?